# Show $\int_{-1}^{1} T_{n}(x)\,dx = \frac{(-1)^{n}+1}{1-n^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

$T_{n}$ being

$$T_{n}(\cos (\theta)) = \cos(n\theta)$$

Could anyone explain me why

$$\int_{-1}^{1} T_{n}(x)\,dx = \frac{(-1)^{n}+1}{1-n^{2}}$$

if $n \neq 1$ and $0$ if $n=1$?

With the integral I came as far as the integral evaluates to

$$ \frac{\cos(n+1)}{n+1}-\frac{\cos(n-1)}{n-1}$$

but from here I am not sure how to get the results with given boundaries.

Comment: Can you [provide more context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960)?  In particular, remind us of the definition of $T_{n}(x)$, and show how you arrived at the result you did.

Comment: Not only more context: what in the world is $\;T_n\;$ ?

Comment: Oh sorry. That's the chebyshev polynomial of the first kind

Comment: I suspect that you did $x=\cos\theta$ but forgot the change of limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward proof.
$$\int_{-1}^1 T_n(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\pi \cos(n\theta)\sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta$$
Now we use the identity
$$\cos(a)\sin(b)=\frac{1}{2}(\sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b))$$
So
$$\int_0^\pi \cos(n\theta)\sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin\big((n+1)\theta\big)-\sin\big((n-1)\theta\big)~\mathrm{d}\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{-1}{n+1}\cos\big((n+1)\theta\big)\bigg]^\pi_0-\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{-1}{n-1}\cos\big((n-1)\theta\big)\bigg]^\pi_0$$
$$\frac{-1}{2(n+1)}\big((-1)^{n+1}-1\big)+\frac{1}{2(n-1)}\big((-1)^{n-1}-1\big)$$
$$=\frac{\big((-1)^{n-1}-1\big)(n+1)-\big((-1)^{n+1}-1\big)(n-1)}{2(n^2-1)}$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n+(-1)^{n-1}-n-1-(-1)^{n+1}n+(-1)^{n+1}+n-1}{2(n^2-1)}$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n-(-1)^2(-1)^{n-1}n+(-1)^{n-1}+(-1)^2(-1)^{n-1}-2}{2(n^2-1)}$$
$$=\frac{2(-1)^{n-1}-2}{2(n^2-1)}=\frac{(-1)^n+1}{1-n^2}.$$
Done.